# File Paths in IDEA InteilliJ

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea, input, path

As the title suggests, I'm having an issue with IntelliJ. For a Java (CS101) assignment I have to do, I need to prompt a user for a string to represent a file path from which an input file should be read. The file is called songwriterData.csv and the path required is /iofiles. Now, I don't have folder or anything called iofiles(that I know of) so my only real issue is configuring my files to have this path so I can drop songwriterData.csv into the path. Here is an example of what the output should read given an incorrect path vs a correct path:

```
Enter path for input file: ioflies/
Looking for ioflies/songwriterData.csv
Cannot find songwriterData.csv. Make sure file exists and path is correct.


Enter path for input file: iofiles/
songwriterData.csv successfully found. Processing will continue.
```

So it should only continue the process when the user types "/iofiles"

Again, I'm not sure how to make this into a valid file path for intelliJ to recognize. Any help at all would be much appreciated.

I've written tester code so far:

```
public static String getInputFile(Scanner console) {
    System.out.print("Enter path for input file:");
    String path = console.nextLine();
    String inputFile = path + "/songwriterData.csv";
    File hello = new File(inputFile);
    System.out.println(inputFile);
    System.out.println(hello.exists());
    return path;
}
```

But when I run the program, passing a scanner from the main method to this method, it returns false (the file doesn't exist). I pasted the file into the project and this didn't help. I essentially need to just get it to return true, that's all.

Comment: I don't think it is an IDE issue. Could you please post the code you have written?

Comment: AFAIK, both Intellij and Eclipse use the project's root path as their base. So just create isoFile folder in your project folder (not in the `src` folder).

Comment: It seems we've figured it out! thanks for the help!

Comment: so what was the problem?

Comment: I just had to create a directory within the project called iofiles then drop the songwriter file in there and then it all worked

Answer (score 0):

Both Intellij Idea and Eclipse use the project's root path as their base. So just create the isoFile folder in your project folder (not in the src folder or other project subfolders).